# not able to send Ajax request with # in parameters

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I am trying to send ajax request. following is the code

```
var parameters = '?dbSid='+dbSid+ '&dbPort='+dbPort+ '&dbIpAddress='+dbIpAddress+    '&dbUserName='+dbUserName+ '&dbPassword='+dbPassword;

new Ajax.Request('../pages/invoke-oracletestAgentCred.jsp'+parameters,   {onSuccess:successFunction , onFailure:errorFunction });
```

If I send `dbPassword` as abcd then it works fine.

But when i send `dbPassword` as #abc it fails and sets the `dbPassword` to blank.

Please help to solve the issue.

Thanks,
Anjali

Comment: It seems you are sending params as queryString, so a # character has a special meaning. Maybe you should replace that char with its url encoding.

Comment: second note... don't send this via ajax... your password will be easily intercepted... you only need an url sniffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The # character has special meaning in URLs (it indicates the start of the document fragment).

Make sure you encode your URL components (with [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using encodeUriComponent?

```
var parameters = '?dbSid='+encodeUriComponent(dbSid)+ '&dbPort='+encodeURIComponent(dbPort)+ '&dbIpAddress='+encodeURIComponent(dbIpAddress)+ '&dbUserName='+encodeURIComponent(dbUserName)+ '&dbPassword='+encodeURIComponent(dbPassword);

new Ajax.Request('../pages/invoke-oracletestAgentCred.jsp'+parameters, {onSuccess:successFunction , onFailure:errorFunction });
```

The reason a # breaks your url is that a # is used to go to a anchor in a page. That's why a browser will cut off any url at an #.